# How to enable igbinary with memcached installed first

Tags: php, memcached, igbinary

I have `memcached` installed with libmemcached. Also I have installed `igbinary`.

This is my php.ini:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
;extension_dir = "./"
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/"

extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=128M

extension=memcached.so
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path="127.0.0.1:11211"

extension=igbinary.so
session.serialize_handler=igbinary
igbinary.compact_strings=On
```

.

When I run phpinfo() i see that igbinary is enabled, but **not** for memcached:

```
apc
Serialization Support   php, igbinary 

igbinary
igbinary support    enabled
igbinary version    1.1.1
igbinary APC serializer ABI     0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
igbinary.compact_strings    On  On
```

Phpinfo() about memcached:

```
memcached
memcached support   enabled
Version     1.0.2
libmemcached version    0.51
Session support     yes
igbinary support    no
```

That last line: `igbinary support` thats the question. Oddly enough, as you can see under the heading apc there is stated: `Serialization Support   php, igbinary`.

So do someone know why I cannot enable igbinary for **memcached**?

Thanks!

Comment: how did your selected answer helped you ? I am in the same situation, but couldn't understand the answer what it means. Can you explain what did you do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the **Memcached::HAVE_IGBINARY** constant to see if your memcached extension was compiled using *--enable-memcached-igbinary*.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php

**Memcached::OPT_SERIALIZER**

> Specifies the serializer to use for serializing non-scalar values. The
>   valid serializers are Memcached::SERIALIZER_PHP or
>   Memcached::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY. The latter is supported only when
>   memcached is configured with --enable-memcached-igbinary option and
>   the igbinary extension is loaded.
>
> Type: integer, default: Memcached::SERIALIZER_PHP.

**Memcached::HAVE_IGBINARY**

> Indicates whether igbinary serializer support is available.
>
> Type: boolean.

Comment: I guess the question was, if memcached was not compiled with enabled-memcached-igbinary, how to change the settings ? or do we have to reinstall memcached again ?

Answer (score 13):

You can't enable it because PECL memcached was not built with '--enable-memcached-igbinary'

PECL install does not take this as a flag, so here is how you can build pecl memcached with it (following example is on ubuntu as root)

```
#if you have libmemcached-dev < 1.0.X need to run: sudo apt-get purge libmemcached-dev
apt-get install libevent-dev
pecl install igbinary    

#cant do sudo pecl install memcached-2.1.0 cuz it wont let me use igbinary
#compiling manually per http://www.neanderthal-technology.com/2011/11/ubuntu-10-install-php-memcached-with-igbinary-support/

#install libmemcached v 1.0.X for pecl memcached 2.1.0
cd /tmp
libmemcached_ver="1.0.15"
wget https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/${libmemcached_ver}/+download/libmemcached-${libmemcached_ver}.tar.gz
tar xzvf libmemcached-${libmemcached_ver}.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-${libmemcached_ver}/
./configure
make
make install
cd ../
rm -r libmemcached-${libmemcached_ver}

#install memcached PECL extension
pecl_memcached_ver="2.1.0"
pecl download memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}
tar xzvf memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}.tgz
cd memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}/
phpize
./configure --enable-memcached-igbinary
make
make install
cd ..
rm -r memcached-${pecl_memcached_ver}

echo "extension=igbinary.so" > /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/igbinary.ini
echo "extension=memcached.so" > /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/memcached.ini

#now restart your PHP server
```

Load up a phpinfo() page and you should now see 'igbinary support: yes' under memcached section.

Comment: Thank you, @rynop !!!!!!!  The other site wasn't quite working, but your instructions did the trick for me.  Huge help.

Comment: np. too bad this isn't documented better as its pretty powerful.

Comment: Worked like a charm in ubuntu 12.04 - thanks! Exact image tried is from puphpet (http://box.puphpet.com/ubuntu-precise12042-x64-vbox43.box)

Answer (score 2):

If you work on a Mac and use MacPorts, you can install the php5-memcached extension with igbinary support with this command:

```
sudo port install php5-memcached +igbinary
```

The `+igbinary` specifies a variant of the `php5-memcached` port.

That command will install an igbinary-enabled memcached extension on your Mac.

You can read more about port variants here: http://guide.macports.org/#using.variants

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to pass configuration options to `pecl install` (see the [PECL manual](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.developers.package2.pecl.php))

Here's how you'd install `memcached` with the `igbinary` serializer, and all other options left at their default values:

```bash
pecl install --configureoptions 'with-libmemcached-dir="no" with-zlib-dir="no" with-system-fastlz="no" enable-memcached-igbinary="yes" enable-memcached-msgpack="no" enable-memcached-json="no" enable-memcached-protocol="no" enable-memcached-sasl="yes" enable-memcached-session="yes"' memcached
```

The full list of options is defined here (look for the `<configureoption>` tags): https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/blob/master/package.xml